# Large File Uploads? SWFUpload?

Tags: upload, video, video-streaming

So, we offer video services and have run into an issue with people uploaded large file sources. I realized that our developer was utilizing php HTTP uploads to handle this and that was causing the slow times & breakdowns.

Now, they keep coming at me wanting to use SWFUpload, quoting it is utilized by YouTube, but I'm adamantly against it because -- well, flash.

However, I don't really know of a -better- solution that works across all browsers.
So I was wondering SWFUpload, which hasn't been updated in a year, is really the viable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really not many options here because of the way HTTP works: you can't upload a huge file because unless you have an INSANELY huge pipe between your user and your server any video of size will take longer than a reasonable HTTP request timeout.
All the workarounds to this have disadvantages - they either require plugins (Java, Flash) or HTML 5 compatibility (new-ish browsers).  There's really no universal "Works Everywhere" solution.

Given the choice, I would say require HTML 5 compatibility (because asking people to install Flash or Java plugins leaves a bad taste in my mouth, but saying "You have to use a recent browser, with HTML 5 compatibility and all the nasty old security holes patched" seems reasonable (your users may disagree however).

The folks over at Stack Overflow [have = discussed the HTML 5 upload magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162102/html-5-file-upload) (and talking about other options to help improve performance), with code samples and reference links - they can probably help you with the implementation details.

Answer (score -1):

[JUpload](http://jupload.sourceforge.net/)

It's a Java applet, so it will work with any browser, as long as Java is installed.  I've used it on an apache server, and it was pretty easy to configure.

Comment: This is really almost as bad as SWFUpload -- it requires Java plugins and a JRE. Not sure what I trust less - random flash applications, or random Java applets :-)